# Наоборот отображать категорию

Tags: php

есть тег

```
if(in_array($element,array(1,4))) continue;
```

1 и 4 это то что мы не хотим выводить, как сделать наоборот, чтобы выводило только 1,4.

```
if(!in_array($element,array(1,4))) continue;
```

так не работает

Answer (score 0):

> *как сделать наоборот, чтобы выводило только 1,4*

Вероятно добавить оператор вывода `echo`:

```
$element = 4;

if (in_array($element, [1, 4])) {
    echo $element;
}
```